# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect to database in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed wamp server on my pc. I can access the phpmyadmin without any errors.

But when I tried to connect to the database in eclipse, for the application, the error is shows up:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.jsp.data_jsp._jspService(data_jsp.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is the data.jsp file:

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="com.mysql.*" %>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<train>
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/train", "root", "*****");
        out.println("connected to database");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("error!!!!");
    }
%>
</train>
```

All the passwords are correct, but I can't find any information on the web that could help me to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: its probably a good idea to hide your password next time :X

Comment: I am using this just for testing... this is the only place where I use this password and I won't be using it enywhere else, bu thanks... :D I will be more carefull next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this command and see if it helps. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON train.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'nezinasi';